# How do I get contract event with filters params use trongrid api?

Tags: tron, tronweb

How do I get contract event logs by filter params like this:

```
https://api.trongrid.io/v1/contracts/TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t/events?only_confirmed=true&event_name=Transfer&limit=200&filters=%7B%22from%22:%220xeaa61073036dcb7af76264e0060f1031191e80ef%22%7D
```

It not working. How can I do this.